# RubyGem on Debian

Tags: debian, ruby, gem

Hello I have this problem while installing many of the gems on my Debian 6 (upped to date).

```
# gem install activemodel
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i486-linux]
# gem -v
1.3.7

# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (3.2.0)
builder (3.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
i18n (0.6.0)
multi_json (1.0.4)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rspec (2.8.0)
rspec-core (2.8.0)
rspec-expectations (2.8.0)
rspec-mocks (2.8.0)
xmpp4r (0.5)
```

Comment: Note that you are using an older version of rubygems.  Current is 1.8.15.  You can do this by running 'gem update --system'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved with installing rubygems from tesing (wheezy).

Answer (score 0):

The gem you are trying to install (`activemodel`) exists in the Debian packaging system (as `ruby-activemodel`) -- May I suggest trying to install it (and any other gems that are in the repository) the Debian Way via `apt`?

This doesn't solve the problem you've mentioned, but it will lead to fewer headaches in the future if everything is using Debian's package management.

Comment: Installing a gem via package makes me wince; it screams of "broken" to me...

Comment: But I'm used to installing ruby and gems from source to control the installed versions.

Comment: @gWaldo I'm not a fan of packages myself, but it is The Debian Way, and if you use Debian you should conform to The Debian Way.  Debian is ***HEAVILY*** dependent on their packaging system (to the extent that it can and will stomp all over your manually-installed gems if some package says you need the gem: It doesn't check to see if it works, it checks to see if the package is installed and at the required revision/version level).

Comment: But this issue also arises with the gems that are not in a package system of Debian. So this is not a solution.